# Can I force SQLPLUS to use NLS_DATE_FORMAT for insert?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to force an implicit date conversion on an insert statement (i.e. without using TO_DATE)?

context: I'm importing a data dump from Postgresql to Oracle.  Everything is working well except for date formatting.  I would prefer not to have to mung the Postgresql output.

(**update:** this is with 10.2.  Strangely, changing the format to RRRR-MM-DD makes everything work!)

```
SQL> create table a(b date);                                                                                                                                                                                              
Table created.

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';                                                                                                                                                                    
Session altered.

SQL> insert into a values('2009-12-03');                                                                                                                                                                                  
insert into a values('2009-12-03')
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month

SQL> insert into a values(to_date('2009-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));                                                                                                                                                            
1 row created.
```

Comment: What version of SQL*Plus are you using?  What version of Oracle?  That should work-- I just verified that when I run your code on my system (Oracle 11.2.0.1 with an 11.2 version of SQL*Plus) that it works.

Comment: I verified it and it works for me too! Can you try `alter session set NLS_date_format='RRRR-MM-DD';` and see if that works?

Comment: Ditto for working with Oracle 10.2.0.4 via SQL Developer.

Comment: Annjawn, thanks, that works!  Make it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Is it possible that your column `b` is really a `timestamp`?  If so, then you would need to set `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.